# Get domain in Zend unitTest

Tags: zend-framework, selenium, phpunit

Can somebody tell me if there are some possibility to get the domain name in unittest and if no how generally this is solved;

Generally in UnitTest there are no such need because you can dispatch something like `/edit.html` and it works right;

For Selenium tests it is more difficult, of course we can hard code it in a variable, but I'm looking for solution to make it work on virtual host `example.com/edit.html` and on localhost: `localhost/example/public/edit.html`;

Comment: You need to be more explicit, perhaps with a non-generic example. First, *where* do you want the domain? Second, are you trying to *set* the domain or *read* it? Normally when testing Zend Framework code using `ControllerTestCase` the domain never enters the picture.

Comment: The domain/IP you pass to `setBrowserUrl()` is wherever you have deployed your application for testing. For us it's a hard-coded IP address, but in your case it may be a real domain or an entry in `/etc/hosts`. How does your application get the domain outside unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

the domain name shouldn't have a bearing on your tests, and you need to mock these things up, be it the controller, view, etc.  You don't run tests against the actual url, you test units of code against those portions of code within, for example, an action in the controller, or method in an action helper, etc.

check out [the phpunit docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)